# When I run the mfc program alone, I encountered a problem,Expression:m_hBitmap!=0

Tags: mfc

[image]

```
CString strBmpPath = _T(".\\res\\bgimg.png");
CImage img;
img.Load(strBmpPath);
MoveWindow(0, 0, img.GetWidth(), img.GetHeight());
CBitmap bmpTmp;
bmpTmp.Attach(img.Detach());
m_bkBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&bmpTmp);
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
```

Comment: `img.Load(strBmpPath)` returns an error/success code. The program doesn't check for success, and when it fails to load the image, `img.Detach()` will fail a debug assertion. There's no `HBITMAP` stored that can be detached.

Comment: Probably the file `".\\res\\bgimg.png"` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of two bugs:

1. Using a relative path (which is **always** wrong) to reference a file system object, and
2. Failure to check for errors (which, again, is **always** wrong)

In detail, what's happening is that `img.Load(strBmpPath)` fails to load the image specified as a relative path. This, presumably, succeeds when run under the debugger, since the IDE helpfully adjusts the current working directory so that the relative path resolves to a file system object.

This generally won't happen when you launch the application outside the IDE. The current working directory then is no longer under your control, and the image file isn't where your code is looking for it.

With `img` not holding a valid image, the call to `img.Detach()` fails the debug assertion, probably something like `ATLASSUME( m_hBitmap != NULL )`.

The immediate fix would be to check for errors when `Load()`-ing the image. Another option would be to construct a fully qualified path to the image resource.

Though, what you *probably* intended to do was to compile *".\res\bgimg.png"* as a binary resource into the executable image, and load it using [CImage::LoadFromResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class#loadfromresource) instead.